# Fluid container, with fluid-fixed-fluid inner layout

Tags: html, css, resize, responsive-design

I've tried to find a solution to the issue mentioned in my title but to no avail.

Basically, I have a fluid `<div>` container with three inner elements (a fixed-width `<img>` element, a fluid width `<textarea>`, a fixed-width `<button>`).

I've already tried a few things with negative margins but with no luck. The `<textarea>`'s length will always trigger the button to wrap below.

I've added a couple of pictures to better describe what i want:
[image: screenshot with lower window width]

and

[image: screenshot with larger window width]

**Edit:** To sum it up, I'd like to have the elements 'cover' that area and not wrap.

**Also**, I'd like to do this by avoiding javascript *resize* listeners. Only pure CSS.

Comment: Try to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have already done

Comment: add a min-width to fliud container otherwise when the window is small container takes the width of window (if it is 100%) so the elemnts inside just dont fit the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using percentages:
id's or classes just used as example.

```
<div id="fluidwrapper" style="width:100%;">
    <div id="imagewrapper" style="float:left;width:100px;">
        <img>noimg</img>
    </div>
    <div id="textandbuttonwrapper" style="width:40%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <textarea style="width:80%;"></textarea>
        <button style="width:20%;">button</button> <!-- okay that is not fixed at all -->
    </div>
</div>
```

white-space:nowrap is actually, what you searching for, i guess.
I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how this solves my problem. The textarea won't extend enough to make all the three elements fill that area (as displayed in the images) and it will break under certain resolutions (okay, it won't wrap but it will break). I've edited my question to better reflect that.

Comment: I tested the code before posting and the textarea always extends. For sure the layout will break in really small resolutions, but therefore you can use mediaqueries (eg http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) Additional you can give the buttontag a flow right, that it always stays there,so you can prevent page breaking.